# Are these three regular expressions valid?

Tags: javascript, regex

- Regular expression 1: check for numbers between 3 and 6.

  ```
  var myRegxp = /^([0-9]){3,6}$/;
  ```
- Regular expression 2: check for numbers between 3 and 6.

  ```
  var myRegxp = /^([0-9_]){3,6}$/;
  ```
- Regular expression3: check for numbers between 3 and 6 and for `dash`.

  ```
  var myRegxp = /^([0-9_-]){3,6}$/;
  ```

Questions:

1. Why do all these work perfectly for numbers matching between 3 and 6?
2. What is the meaning of `_` (underscore) in the second and the third expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of these checks for a 3 to 6 characters sequence.

The first allows 3 digits only.

The second allows 3 characters, but also including underscores in addition to digits.

The third allows 3 characters, but also including underscores and dashes in addition to digits.

Whether these are "valid" or not depends upon what you're trying to accomplish.  The dash is useful to allow negative numbers, though a more rigorous regex would require the dash to be in the first position and would still allow 3 to 6 additional digits.

In answer to your question about the underscore, it is just another allowable character in the third regex.  It's a perfectly legal regex.

---

If you dissect the third regular expression, you get this:

`^` means the start of the string you are matching

`()` means to capture what is between the parens separately in the results.  It doesn't affect what matches, but affects how the matches results are returned.

`[]` denotes a character set where it can match anything in those brackets.

`[0-9]` denotes a range of characters where any character between 0 and 9 will constitute a match.

`[0-9_-]` denotes the same range as above, but also includes the underscore character and the hyphen character.

`{3,6}` means that you want to match 3-6 occurrences of the previous regex element.

`$` means the end of the string

---

So, in the third regex, you're looking for the beginning of the string, followed by 3-6 characters that can be a numeric digit, an underscore or a hyphen followed by the end of the string.

---

By way of example:

```
"444" - matches all three
"-44" - matches the second or third
"_-4" - matches the third
"4"   - matches none
```

---

If you want a regex that allowed 3-6 digits and could be positive or negative, then you would use something like this:

```
/^[+\-]?\d{3,6}$/
```

This allows an optional leading hyphen or plus, followed by 3-6 digits.

Comment: All the three are perfectly valid?.

Comment: @Kevin - they are valid regular expressions that each accomplish slightly different things.

Answer (score 4):

The `[0-9]` means "anything in the range from `0` to `9`", or in other words, a digit (which could be also represented with `\d`). The parentheses indicate grouping, but are unnecessary here. The `{3,6}` means "the previous thing must appear three to six times". The `^` and `$` indicate that the regular expression must match the whole string.

The underscore in the `[]` indicates that it, too, along with the digits is a valid character.

They are all valid regular expressions, but do different things:

- The first one allows only three to six digits.
- The second one allows only three to six digits or underscores.
- The third one allows only three to six digits, underscores, or hyphens.

Which one you'd want to use depends on what data you consider valid. If a hyphen is invalid, for example, you'd not want to use the third one because it accepts hyphens. If you want to disallow underscores, then you'd better use the first one, because all the other ones allow underscores. You can even make a regular expression to allow digits and dashes but not underscores rather trivially: `/^[\d-]{3,6}$/`